# Undefined React check

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-typescript

I am trying to write a check for localStorage being undefined, but I get the following error upon writing the checks

[image]

[image]

How do I actually test for localStorage being defined, I understand it is not even set as a variable in Javascript when I refresh the page in React due to server side rendering.